# Prevent change of selected tab in WPF ribbon

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I'm using the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010. Is there a way to prevent the user from changing the tab? I've tried setting handled to true in selection changed.

Comment: Place everything into one tab?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting handled to true in the click tunneling event at the tab header level.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what event you are meaning